# What do I need to learn to become a better web programmer?

Tags: web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should every programmer know about web development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development)

I'm 15 years old. I've been programming for 2 years. I suppose I am a good programmer (not designer).
I can use PHP(Good), Css(simple), and JQuery(not too bad).

What else can I learn related to web development (maybe system programming)?
Thanks for your suggestions..

Comment: In order to be a good programmer you must be able to communicate with your peers.  Please revise your question, so what you are asking, is perfectly clear.  At this point your inability to communicate, will make it very hard, to become a programmer of any significant skill level.

Comment: This question will probably get closed, but you're young so I'll just say that my advice is to learn, learn, and learn some more. This industry is great, you are able to teach yourself a stack of information!

Comment: Sorry for my English.. I'm not English. I'm From Turkey..

Comment: @AndyC what i must learn?

Comment: Anything that interests you. This field reaches far and wide. There is no right or wrong answer here.

Comment: +1 to compensate for the downvote. Let's not be rude with newbies, OK? :-) Sure this question could be improved, but IMHO it is a honest attempt and the topic is extremely important. We do want to have good and motivated junior programmers on this field don't we?

Comment: @PéterTörök: I don't think it was meant to be rude, it's just unlikely to receive high quality answers and/or be useful to a large subset of people who frequent this site.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, and is this already reason enough to *downvote*?

Comment: @PéterTörök: I don't see anything wrong with giving a single downvote to a low quality question, but that's just a personal opinion.  And to address your earlier comment about good junior programmers.  I'd say a vital part of being a good programmer is being able to accept criticism and consider it a learning opportunity as opposed to taking it personally.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, what makes you think the OP took criticism personally? I don't see any such comment here, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: My advice: Read books. Which books? Google for "recommended programmer books" and read all of them. You're 15 years old, you have time.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to become good at anything, wether it is programming, playing an instrument or a physical activity is to practice. Write lots of code. Try to learn as much as you can along the way. Read other peoples code as well as books and articles about programming. Try out the stuff that you learn. And never think you have learnt it all. There's always more to learn, and another field to master.

Comment: And read books about best practices, study and save good posts from stack overflow and this site.

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, I just recommended [*The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master*](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer) in an [answer to a different question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113683/what-are-ways-i-can-speed-of-development-time-when-building-applications/113686#113686), but it will do good to you too :-)

This book is what its title promises. It will show you what it takes to become a good programmer, and what are all the different areas, activities and skills involved in producing software. What is IMHO the most important is, it gives you the big picture, and teaches you the mindset to become a successful developer: one who is able to solve his clients' problems efficiently.

Comment: This book is elementary reading, but not sure it will catch on to a 15 year old. If it does however, it'll be a great foundation!

Comment: Maybe I'm 15 years old. But i'm not bad programmer :) @harald

Comment: @Programmer, I didn't say that you were. And that you are seeking more knowledge is the best sign for the future. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to plenty of reading and practice, make friends with others who have the same interest. Becoming part of a community of people all interested in doing the same thing will answer the question you're asking permanently.

But to answer your question more specifically, you should learn something about data persistence (databases, etc.). Try MySQL since you already have some PHP. The two go together like peas in a pod.